# Box2D origin of multiple fixtures

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I think when you apply force to a body it is applied to origin of body ( could be center of mass ). Now I am trying to to create tetris-like blocks and make them jump by applying linearPulse like this:

```
body.applyLinearImpulse(0, 5f, this.body.getPosition().x, this.body.getPosition().y, true);
```

this works excellent if you only have one box fixture as body, but when you create multiple fixtures the origin gets misplaced and I can't place it to center of fixture.

Here is picture of what I mean:

[image: Demonstration]

I create fixtures from matrix like this:

```
int array[][]= {{0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,1,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0}};
```

and I use array to create fixtures like this:

```
public void setBody(int[][] blocks){
        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
        def.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        def.position.set(new Vector2(100 * WORLD_TO_BOX, 100 * WORLD_TO_BOX));
        Body body = world.createBody(def);
        body.setTransform(150*WORLD_TO_BOX, 200*WORLD_TO_BOX, -90*MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) { // HARDCODED 5
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) { // HARDCODED 5
                if(blocks[x][y] == 1){
                    PolygonShape poly = new PolygonShape();
                    Vector2 v = new Vector2((-5/2+x),(-5/2+y));
                    poly.setAsBox(size/2 * WORLD_TO_BOX, size/2 * WORLD_TO_BOX, v, 0);
                    body.createFixture(poly, 1);
                    poly.dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        this.body = body;
    }
```

**WORLD_TO_BOX** values is 0.032f
and **size** of one block is 32f

so my guestion is, how can I manually set center of mass/origin of my complex multifixture body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you get to set the center of mass for a body, it is calculated by the system.  From the manual:

> You can access the center of mass position in local and world
>   coordinates. Much of the internal simulation in Box2D uses the center
>   of mass. However, you should normally not need to access it. Instead
>   you will usually work with the body transform. For example, you may
>   have a body that is square. The body origin might be a corner of the
>   square, while the center of mass is located at the center of the
>   square.

```
const b2Vec2& GetPosition() const;  
float32 GetAngle() const; 
￼￼￼￼￼￼const b2Vec2& GetWorldCenter() const;   
const b2Vec2& GetLocalCenter()
```

I believe you will use GetWorldCenter() as the linear impulse is applied in world coordinates (also per the manual):

> You can apply forces, torques, and impulses to a body. When you apply
>   a force or an impulse, you provide a world point where the load is
>   applied.

Was this helpful?

Comment: so in order to make it behave as I want I need to do it like this:
body.setLinearImpulse(0,5f,body.getLocalCenter().x,body.getLocalCenter().y)? I tried it but it makes the body spin very very fast instead of being stable

Comment: I believe you need to use GetWorldCenter().